# UCP: Unable to successfully setup local node. Run "docker logs ucp-reconcile" for more details

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, docker-swarm, ucp

I am trying to install and launch UCP on docker EE and I am getting the above error.
I am using the below command to launch UCP:

```
docker container run --rm -it --name ucp \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  docker/ucp:3.1.1 install \
  --host-address <ip-host-address> \
  --interactive
```

I then run

```
docker logs ucp-reconcile
```

and it just says there is no such container.

The only warning I get is

```
Unauthorized users may be able to access this node since it's listening on port 2375.
```

but it is a warning and shouldn't affect the deployment of the UCP on a swarm.

I am not able to understand what needs to be done in order to get this up.

Answer (score 0):

You should never run docker in a way that it will listen on port 2375. That is the same as completely disabling the root password on your whole system for the entire network. UCP sets up a way for you to access the cluster securely, so there is no need to open up your node insecurely.

The UCP installer is trying to tell you this. I was able to recreate your situation by first setting my docker.service unit file's ExecStart line to this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

I then ran: `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker` to make the changes take effect.

I then ran the UCP installer as follows:

```
$ docker run --rm -it         -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock         docker/ucp         install --force-minimums
INFO[0000] Your engine version 18.09.0, build 33a45cd (3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64) is compatible with UCP 3.1.2 (b822777)
FATA[0003] The Docker port is externally accessible on this node, accepting connections on port 2375. This node is insecure. Learn more at https://docker.com/ddc-18
```

This is totally expected behavior from the installer. Don't run Docker in this manner.

Comment: How should I remedy this? Should I block my 2375 port?

Comment: Change your docker configuration to not listen on 2375 at all.

Comment: Consider reinstalling your system and recovering from a backup.  It's extremely easy to remotely compromise a system configured this way.

Comment: I know only how to make docker open to ports, I am unable to find documentation to deny docker service to any ports.